# Looping through a parent / Child structure

Tags: c#, .net

I'm working on a game where it will be possible to target each mob's limbs specifically, so you could aim for the head, the legs, ...

I have this constructor:

```
public Humanoid(Race race, Gender gender, string firstname, string lastname = null)
{
    this.Legs = new List<Leg> { new Leg(), new Leg() };
    this.Torso = new Torso();
    this.Arms = new List<Arm> { new Arm(), new Arm() };
    this.Heads = new List<Head>
    {
        new Head
        {
            Ears = new List<Ear> { new Ear(), new Ear() },
            Eyes = new List<Eye> { new Eye(), new Eye() }
        }
    };
}
```

All of these limbs inherit from interface `ILimb`.

What is the best way to be able to loop through all limbs, including childs (when applicable)?

I could add a `protected List<ILimb> { get; set; }` and then add each, but that's redundant.

Any ideas or suggestions for improvement?

Comment: i would use the `System.Reflection` library with custom attributes. tag your limbs with some attribute then use the reflection library to get the properties of Humanoid, and then filter that list based off custom attributes. then you have a list of all your `ILimb`s that you can iterate through https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a4a92379(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Concat the `Legs` and `Arms` list together and loop through them.

Comment: @MattBurland: How do you mean concat?

Comment: I 'think' it's possible to request an instance's properties without it needing an attribute. Anyhow, it's worth looking in to.

Comment: On the subject of redundancy, you are dealing with two lists with two members. If you have another list of limbs, then you have another list of 4 items. That hardly seems worth worrying about. It's probably more efficient than mucking about with reflection, for example. Even just adding the code to iterate `Arms` and then `Legs` hardly seems that big of a burden.

Answer (score 3):

The best way would be to have this structure instead:

```
public Humanoid(Race race, Gender gender, string firstname, string lastname = null)
{
    this.Limbs = new List<ILimb>();
    this.Limbs.Add(new Legs() { Limbs = new List<Limb>() { new Leg(), new Leg() });
    this.Limbs.Add(new Torso());
    this.Limbs.Add(new Arms() { Limbs = new List<Limb>() { new Arm(), new Arm() });
    this.Limbs.Add(new Heads() { Limbs = new List<Limb>() { new Head() { Limbs = new List<Limb>() .... , ... });
}
```

you can tidy the code up but basically it should have a collection of limbs, and limbs should have collections of limbs so that you can have Head > Ears > Ear or whatever hierarchy you wish.

Then in your ILimb interface, give it a Limbs property

```
public interface ILimb
{
    List<ILimb> Limbs { get; set; }
    List<ILimb> GetAllLimbs { get; }
}
```

And create an abstract base class Limb with this method:

```
public virtual GetAllLimbs()
{
// pseudocode: something like this (basically recurse through the children)
return this.Limbs().foreach (c => c.GetAllLimbs()).union(this.Limbs());
}
```

Then it can crawl down the hierarchy easily and retrieve every limb.

So you could do

`myHumanoid.GetAllLimbs().Where(c => c is Arm).TakeDamage(5);`

for example.

Comment: Torsos and Heads aren't limbs. But otherwise, the general principle that they should change their structure isn't a bad one

Comment: In real life, no, but for the purposes of the game they could be. Or you could change it to `BodyPart` or something similar. The concept of 'Heads'  is not a real thing either, it is just an object that the author has used to group multiple heads. I don't think it's actually necessary, the heads could be added to the root object, and you can get all heads quite easily.

Comment: @SLC: Correct, the multiple head thing is to cover things like two-headed Ogres or something similar. Or hydras, though that's not of the humanoid implementation, obviously.

Comment: With this technique there is no need to store a list of heads, a list of arms, etc. as you can just add them all to the 'limbs' list on the humanoid. So an `arms` and `legs` class is not required

Comment: @SLC: The point of the parent child structure is that the head (as a whole) counts as a main region. Arms, torso and legs are one as well. That way I could add some randomness to generic attacks and determine which part they hit (and apply appropriate effect). And for really precise strikes, such as an aimed bow shot, you could target an eye specifically, for instance.

Comment: And also, it makes it easier to add levels of chance-to-hit. I mean, suppose you have a general chance to hit the head with a generic attack of 15%. Then, 'if' you hit the head, you have like a 5% to hit chance for each eye and ear, leaving you with a more likely 80% of doing flesh damage.

Comment: You can still do that, by adding an Eye, Mouth etc. to Head. Or a more complex one like Arm>Hand>Finger. But there's no reason to add Head to a 'Heads' object within the hierarchy because you don't need to group them together. You can just add multiple heads, and select them all using a filter like `GetHeads this.Limbs.Where(c => c is Head);`

Answer (score 1):

You have custom models for all of your objects except one... a custom *collection* of models.  `List<T>` is a good start, but it doesn't have the functionality you're looking for.  Functionality you're *trying* to put into `Humanoid` but doesn't really belong there.

Implement something like this:

```
public class LimbList<T> : IList<T> where T : ILimb
{
    // implement IList<T> here
}
```

Here you would include business logic for the collection of limbs.  For example:

- If there are already 2 `Arm` objects in the backing collection, throw an exception when calling `.Add()` with an `Arm` object.
- If there is already 1 `Torso` object in the backing collection, throw an exception when calling `.Add()` with a `Torso` object.
- etc.

A `Humanoid` would then have  a `LimbList<ILimb>` property:

```
public Humanoid(Race race, Gender gender, string firstname, string lastname = null)
{
    this.Limbs.Add(new Leg());
    this.Limbs.Add(new Leg());
    this.Limbs.Add(new Torso());
    this.Limbs.Add(new Arm());
    this.Limbs.Add(new Arm());
    this.Limbs.Add(new Head
        {
            // as an added exercise, how would you extend this concept to the Head object?
        });
}
```

And you can loop over that list easily:

```
foreach (var limb in this.Limbs)
```

---

Essentially the point here is that a collection of objects is itself an object, with custom logic like any other object.  Put object logic in the objects, put collection logic in the collections.  There's no rule that says you must *only* use the built-in collections in the framework.

Comment: Interesting suggestion, I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Given a `legs` list and an `arms` list, you can do this:

```
IEnumerable<ILimb> limbs = ((IEnumerable<ILimb>)arms).Concat(legs);
```

And then iterate it:

```
foreach (var limb in limbs) 
{
    // limb is an ILimb and you can access anything in that interface 
    // for each limb
}
```

Another alternative is you could add a method to `Humanoid` like this:

```
public IEnumerable<ILimb> GetLimbs() 
{
    foreach (var a in Arms)
    {
        yield return a;
    }
    foreach (var l in Legs)
    {
        yield return l;
    }
}
```

Then you could do something like:

```
foreach(var limb in someHumanoid.GetLimbs()) 
{

}
```